# Accessing a member function from a vector of pointers? C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, vector, member

So, lets say I have a vector,  `vector<Item*> vItem` and an Item class with a member function `Item::setValue();`. Lets also say I populated that vector by using `vItem.push_back(new Item)`.

Now, to access that member function, through the pointer in the vector, would `vItem[0]->setValue("key");`. be valid? I assumed it was, however when I `cout` the member variables using a `getValue()` function, nothing new is returned, only the default values from my constructor.

Any ideas? I feel like it's a stupid mistake in my logic, but I'm not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDITS:

setValue code:

```
void Item::setValue(string sValue)
{
        m_sValue = sValue;
}
```

with the private variable:

```
string m_sValue;
```

getValue code:

```
string Item::getValue()
{
    return m_sValue;
}
```

Simple version of the code:

```
void func2(vector<Item*>& vItem)
{
    vItem.push_back(new Item);
    vItem[0]->setValue("key");
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    vector<Item*> vItem;
    func2(vItem);
    cout << vItem[0]->getValue() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I should also note: everything compiles just fine (g++ using c++0x standard) however, the setter just doesn't set.

Comment: Your description sound correct. could you post setValue code?

Comment: Try simplifying this down to about 10 lines of code showing an insertion, a call to setValue, all call to getValue, the code for Item, and what behavior you're seeing.  It'll be a lot easier to help spot the problem this way.

Comment: @billz added the setValue code. Going to add a simple version too.

Comment: setValue also looks fine.

Comment: @MrFooz Added a simple version of the code.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/Utvemk). The problem must needs lie in the code you haven't shown.

Answer (score 0):

Your getValue returns a void and there's an out-of-place semi-colon after `getValue()` in your implementation of that method. Change to `string Item::getValue(){return m_sValue;}`

Comment: My apologies, I accidentally set it as void on here. I did correctly set it as a string in the real program. Thanks though

Comment: you still have an added semi-colon. `string Item::getValue();`

Comment: I tested your code, and it runs fine and outputs the expected result. To check that the setter is working right, cout the private string var at the end of your setValue method to ensure that m_sValue = sValue